# Android application does not support this device, emulator samsung galaxy s4

Tags: android, c++, emulation

When I run my application in C++ on RAD studio XE8, the emulator galaxy s4 says "Application does not support this device". Even if i already unchecked the

Local Name: libnative-activity.so
 Remote Path: library\lib\armeabi\

I rebuild it, erased it, reinstalled it, cleaned it. I don't know what to do.

Thank you

Comment: A little more context on the issue would help. This is too broad

Comment: It's only an application Hello Wolrd. I'm trying to emulate it on a samsung galaxy s4 black. The application works fine on my galaxy s4 but doesn't on the emulator. I know that s4s are using a ARM CPU but I used the intel(x86) on the emulator because it's 10x faster. I found that I needed to unchecked one library but doesn't change anything. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the basics. Emulators will always be x86 because they run inside your laptop's CPU. Physical devices are (almost) always ARM